# Как передать информацию из данных FSM машины состояний в Callback inline кнопки в python aiogram telegram bot?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram

Пишу бота для принятия заявок на работу. Мне нужно чтобы при нажатии кнопки 'accept' отправлялось определённое сообщение изначальному пользователю, который запустил заполнение анкеты. Я всё перепробовал, но так и не понял как правильно получить *message.from_user.id* в колбэке кнопки, чтобы после её нажатия ему отправилось какое-либо сообщение.

Код отвечающий за это:

```
class FormState(StatesGroup):
    exp = State()
    wh = State()
    formlog = State()
    user_id = State()

markup = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, one_time_keyboard=True)
remove = ReplyKeyboardRemove()
imarkup = InlineKeyboardMarkup()

@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def process_start_command(message: Message):
    if message.chat.type == 'private':
        sbtn = KeyboardButton('Начать')
        markup.add(sbtn)
        await message.answer(' Добро пожаловать на форму подачи заявки в нашу команду! Для начала заполните анкету и ответьте на несколько вопросов.', reply_markup=markup)
        await FormState.exp.set()

@dp.message_handler(state=FormState.exp, text=['Начать'])
async def get_exp(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    await message.answer('Был ли у вас до этого опыт? Если да, то какой?', reply_markup=remove)
    await FormState.next()

@dp.message_handler(state=FormState.wh)
async def get_wh(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    await state.update_data(exp=message.text)
    await message.answer('Сколько часов в день вы готовы уделять работе?')
    await FormState.next()

@dp.message_handler(state=FormState.formlog)
async def form_finish(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    await state.update_data(wh=message.text, user_id=message.from_user.id)
    data = await state.get_data()
    abutton = InlineKeyboardButton(text='✅', callback_data='accept')
    dbutton = InlineKeyboardButton(text='❌', callback_data='butt_id')
    msg = InlineKeyboardButton(text='✉️', callback_data='butt_id')
    imarkup.add(abutton, dbutton, msg)
    await bot.send_message(config.adminid,  f' <b>Новая заявка на вступление!</b>\n\n Пользователь: <b>{message.from_user.mention}</b>\n'
                                            f' Опыт: <b>{data["exp"]}</b>\n'
                                            f' Часы работы в день: <b>{data["wh"]}</b>', reply_markup=imarkup)
    await message.answer('⏳ <b><i>Ваша заявка успешно подана на рассмотрение</i></b>')

@dp.callback_query_handler(text='accept')
async def accept_query(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    await call.message.edit_text(call.message.text+'\n\n✅ <i>Вы одобрили эту заявку</i>')
    await call.bot.send_message(user_id='???', '✅ <b>Ваша заявка была одобрена!</b>')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Примерно так

```
abutton = InlineKeyboardButton(text='✅', callback_data=f'accept:{message.from_user.id}')
dbutton = InlineKeyboardButton(text='❌', callback_data=f'butt_id:{message.from_user.id}')

@dp.callback_query_handler(text_startswith='accept')
async def accept_query(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    user_id = call.data.split(":")[1]
```